# Removing auto generated style attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi,

I have a

```
<span style="display: none; ">
```

that is generated in my code, and I cant figure out why "display: none;" is set.

I have tried using:

```
$('span').removeAttr('style');
```

and

```
$('span').attr('style', '')
```

...but none of them are working.

Somehow

```
$('span').removeAttr(style);
```

is working, but of cource that give an error due to the missing '' around style.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If `$('span').removeAttr(style);` is "working", you might have some JavaScript code which sets style *after* that line and is not executed due to that error. That would explain why the others don't work.

Answer (score 1):

`$('span').show()` should remove the display:none

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('span').css('display', 'inline');
```